# Custom download servlet

Tags: jsf, servlets, download

I looked into BalusC's code for a custom download servlet from absolute path (see http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html#FileServletServingFromAbsolutePath). I'm not a Java Web Developer Expert so I would love if someone can explainme this part of the code

```
private String filePath;

// Actions ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public void init() throws ServletException {

    // Define base path somehow. You can define it as init-param of the servlet.
    this.filePath = "/files";

    // In a Windows environment with the Applicationserver running on the
    // c: volume, the above path is exactly the same as "c:\files".
    // In UNIX, it is just straightforward "/files".
}
```

When does the init method gets called? Why do we need the filePath to be set in the init method?

I have an XHTML (Mojarra+IceFaces) with something like the code below that works great. My page is missing just the part of downloading the file which is referenced by the `outputLink` tag

```
                <ice:tree id="tree"
                          value="#{treeBean.model}"
                          var="item"
                          hideRootNode="false"
                          hideNavigation="false"
                          >
                    <ice:treeNode>
                        <f:facet name="icon">
                            <ice:panelGroup style="display: inline">
                                <h:graphicImage value="#{item.userObject.icon}" />
                            </ice:panelGroup>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="content">
                            <ice:panelGroup style="display: inline-block">
                                <ice:outputLink value="#{item.userObject.filePath}">
                                    <ice:outputText value="#{item.userObject.fileName}"/>
                                </ice:outputLink>
                            </ice:panelGroup>
                        </f:facet>
                    </ice:treeNode>
                </ice:tree>
```

In my Backing bean I have two fields `fileName` (just the name of the filewith extension e.g. Image.jpeg) and `filepath` (the ABSOLUTE path of the file in the server). Finally I want to download the file with the custom servelet, how can I do that??

Cheers,

**UPDATE**

Let's say mi base-dir is `/SRC` and under that dir I have all my xhtml pages and the WEB-INF and META-INF and aditionally I have a dir called **dataFiles** under dataFiles I have the following structure

```
  --dataFiles
  |----Enterprise1
  |    |--User1
  |    |   |--goodFiles
  |    |   |  |--ok.txt
  |    |   |--badFiles
  |    |      |--bad.txt
  |    |--User2 
  |    |   |--goodFiles
  |    |   |  |--ok.txt
  |    |   |--badFiles
  |    |      |--bad.txt
  |----Enterprise2
       |--User1
       |   |--goodFiles
       |   |  |--ok.txt
       |   |--badFiles
       |      |--bad.txt
       |--User2 
           |--goodFiles
           |  |--ok.txt
           |--badFiles
              |--bad.txt
```

that's how I render the tree with IceFaces and I just have the filename in the backing bean (i.e. ok.txt or bad.txt) but I cannot figure out how to download the file pointing by the link in the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally got it work.

First of all thanks to BalusC, there were some posts here that helped me understand but someone delete them. Anyway, here's what I've learned.

1. In Servlet's **init** method the **filePath** variable must point to the ***absolute*** path where the files to download are.
2. In the **web.xml** the servlet-map-url-pattern will cause to execute the servlet when the browser has that url pattern.
3. In the xhtml page tha value of the link should begin with the url-pattern followed by the name (or a path+FileName) so when you click the link the download begins.

That's all I had to do !

In the example of the question, the filePath variable in the servlet's init method will point to the absolute path, something like **C:\myApp\dataFiles**
Then in the xhtml will call the servlet with something like

```
<ice:outputLink value="dl/myPath/#{myBean.fileName}>
    <ice:outputText value="#{myBean.fileName}"/>
</ice:outputLink>
```

Note 1:  that the first part of the value of the outputLink is **dl/** this is because the url-pattern for the servlet to download is mapped to it

Note 2: in the outputLink the value of **myPath** could be **dl/Enterprise1/User1/file1.ext**

Cheers

Comment: I've deleted it myself because the question became way too broad and too localized and I didn't see your real problem anymore. It just wasn't worth the effort to spend more time on figuring/guessing your concrete problem.

Comment: Think you're right. But thanks anyway, with your advise I solved my problem.